# What is the topological explanation of the gauge covariant derivative?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, topology, gauge-invariance

Non-topologically speaking, a gauge covariant derivative is different to a regular derivative as it **introduces** **a** **correction term** that maintains invariance of the action of a Lagrangian under a gauge transformation. However, if you then adopt a topological lens, and think of the gauge transformations as a manifold, then how does the introduction of aforementioned correction term change this manifold in a way that results in invariance of the 'physics'.

I am being very abstract and ambiguous here as unfortunately I do not know enough to ask a specific and technically correct question. Nevertheless, I hope the general gist of my question is conveyed. Another way to think of my question is, how does redefining the derivative topologically result in invariance/symmetry? Perhaps the question itself is flawed, in which case I hope someone is able to tell me in what way it is.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a question with a book-length answer. You will find a complete explanation in Baez and Muñain, *Gauge fields, knots, and gravity* or Naber, *Topology, Geometry, and Gauge Fields*, 2 vols.

Comment: Well, even without topology but with diferentiable metric manifolds, the covariant derivative is what defines, or can be derived from, parallel transport. You need to involve some mechanism to compare things at two different tangent spaces, i.e. the closest thing to having two equal vectors at two spacetime or manifold points. Invariance then simply comes from Lie derivatives, which is a way to figure out what happens when you get parallel transported around a circuit and back to the same spacetime point; it tells you if some vector filed (the Killing field) commutes with the manifold metric.

Comment: Hey Bob, thanks for your comment! Could you just explain something:

- How do Lie derivatives give information about invariance? Is it because: If the Lie derivative of a vector at a certain point on the spacetime manifold with respect to a circuit along the Lie manifold (given by the gauge transformation) is 0, then there is invariance? 

I was just a little confused about what is being parallel transported, and along what circuit.

Comment: @BobBee was I right in what I wrote in my previous comment? That would help clarify some of the confusion I have. Thank you

Comment: @K.T.  I'll reply later today, sorry didn't see it before

Comment: I misspoke. Parallel transport has nothing to do with it, it would have to do to do with changes along connections. The Lie derivative is the change of a tensor field along the flow (or integral curve) of a vector field. For a vector field its Lie derivative is the commutator with the other vector field. For the metric or other tensor, it measures it's change along the flow of a vector field. If that is zero for the metric then it is indeed a spacetime symmetry, like you said. Look up Lie derivatives at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative. And Google spacetime symmetries